# Pointer to pointer in struct C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure

Here is the structure

```
typedef struct PSetting 
{
unsigned char Level;
unsigned int Mall;
unsigned int Many;
WCHAR* Name; // optional
} PSetting;

PSetting p;
p.Name = L"NewName";
p.Level = 5;
p.Mall= 0;
p.Mall= 0;
```

I am required to create a member for the structure and pass it to this API:

```
PSettingAPI(proxy, PSetting **p, NULL)
```

However, I have this error when I do so:

```
no suitable conversion function from "PSetting" to "Psetting **" exists.
```

Comment: The problem is with how you're calling the API. You need to pass a pointer to an array of `PSetting` structures, but you're passing the `PSetting` itself.

Comment: Is `PSettingAPI(proxy, PSetting **p, NULL)` a call to the API, or the API definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass an object of type `PSetting` directly. The API function expects a pointer to a pointer to `PSetting` (PSetting **p) as the second parameter.

```
PSetting p;
PSetting* pointerToPSetting = &p;
PSetting** pointerToPointerToPSetting = &pointerToPSetting;
```

Now pass pointerToPointerToPSetting to the function. Note that this could be a two-dimensional array of `PSetting`.